# Most possible pairs

Tags: python

Given a list of values, and information on possible matches, is there an efficient way to determine the fewest number of values left out of a pair? For instance

```
values = [1,2,3,4]
matches[1] = [4]
matches[2] = [3, 4]
matches[3] = [2]
matches[4] = [1, 2]
```

Possible pairings here could be

```
[(1,4),(2,3)]
[(2,4)]
```

Of which the former is best, leaving 0 unpaired.

Possible matches for any element in the list can be any set of values, but the relationship is symmetric. Values CAN have repeats

I could certainly generate all possible pairings and test each one, but that's quite slow. Trying to do it as a sort of tree - generating possible matches (or no-match), removing the pair from the list, and returning the number of unmatched after the list is exhausted - works, but slows down dramatically as soon as I hit list sizes in the 20s (mind, this might just be my implementation).

Internally I have the information on matches as a dictionary, where

```
matches[i] = [j for j in range(len(values)) if ismatch(values[j], values[i])]
```

which may or may not be efficient in itself.

Comment: Is `matches[n]` supposed to be a list of values that `n` is allowed to be matched with? Your description is unclear.

Comment: It sounds like this is just the [maximum matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)), which you should go read about.